# Spring kafka setErrorHandler deprecated replacement (boot 2.6.4)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

On spring boot 2.6.4, this method is deprecated.

```java
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>();
        configurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory());

        // deprecated
        factory.setErrorHandler(new GlobalErrorHandler());

        return factory;
    }
```

The global error handler class

```java
public class GlobalErrorHandler implements ConsumerAwareErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> data, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        // my custom global logic (e.g. notify ops team via slack)
    }

}
```

What is the replacement sample for this? The doc says I should use `setCommonErrorHandler`, but how to implements the `CommonErrorHandler` interface, as no method to be overriden there.

Point is, I have to send slack notification to ops team, based on certain condition (the message tpye, which is available on kafka message header)

This is not blocking, just an annoying deprecated message though.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Spring for Apache Kafka documentation; legacy error handlers are replaced with `CommonErrorHandler` implementations.

**What's New?**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#x28-eh

> The legacy GenericErrorHandler and its sub-interface hierarchies for record an batch listeners have been replaced by a new single interface CommonErrorHandler with implementations corresponding to most legacy implementations of GenericErrorHandler. See Container Error Handlers for more information.

**Container Error Handlers**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handlers

> Starting with version 2.8, the legacy `ErrorHandler` and `BatchErrorHandler` interfaces have been superseded by a new `CommonErrorHandler`. These error handlers can handle errors for both record and batch listeners, allowing a single listener container factory to create containers for both types of listener. CommonErrorHandler implementations to replace most legacy framework error handler implementations are provided and the legacy error handlers deprecated. The legacy interfaces are still supported by listener containers and listener container factories; they will be deprecated in a future release.

Comment: Watched the doc, but no concrete implementation sample of `myErrorHandler` in this snippet : `factory.setCommonErrorHandler(myErrorHandler);`. The samples are using `DefaultErrorHandler`, which not sufficient in my case (need custom logic to notify ops team on slack). Any example on how to implement class `MyErrorHandler`? I suppose it should implements interface `CommonErrorHandler`, but all methods there are marked as `default`, hence the implementation is not clear

Comment: Previously I'm using `public class KafkaSlackErrorHandler implements ConsumerAwareErrorHandler`, which needs 1 method (`handle`) to be overriden, but can't find the exact method to be overriden on both spring kafka interface `CommonErrorHandler`, or class `DefaultErrorHandler`

Comment: To replace a `ConsumerAwareErrorHandler `, you should implement `handleRecord` and leave `remainingRecords()` to return `false` (default). You should also implement `handleOtherException` - to handle exceptions that occur outside the scope of record processing (e.g. consumer errors). See the javadocs in `CommonErrorHandler`.

Comment: I added some clarification to the docs https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2145

Comment: The handleRecord() method implementation is deprecated starting from 2.9 and I am using SpringBoot 3.0.2.
Any thoughts on getting around this or an alternative/replacement?
@GaryRussell

Comment: `handleOne()` - see the Javadocs https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/73bee667dbaabca11ceee22a8d70b09934932d5f/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/CommonErrorHandler.java#L96-L97

Answer (score 7):

I was facing exactly the same problem, so I changed the method implementation ConsumerAwareErrorHandler by

> CommonErrorHandler

and implemented

> handleRecord

like described in the docs and it works!

```
public class GlobalErrorHandler implements CommonErrorHandler {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalErrorHandler.class);

  @Override
  public void handleRecord(
      Exception thrownException,
      ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record,
      Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
      MessageListenerContainer container) {
    log.warn("Global error handler for message: {}", record.value().toString());
  }
}
```

In KafkaConfig.class

```
  @Bean(value = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory());

    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new GlobalErrorHandler());

    return factory;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is on the the newer versions of Spring-Boot 3.0.x, here is the implementation based on @GarryRussel's input:
handleRecord() has been deprecated from Spring Boot 2.9
handleOne() is its replacement.

```
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new CommonErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleOne(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
            return CommonErrorHandler.super.handleOne(thrownException, record, consumer, container);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleOtherException(Exception thrownException, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container, boolean batchListener) {
            CommonErrorHandler.super.handleOtherException(thrownException, consumer, container, batchListener);
        }
    });
```